# Data-bound h1 tag not showing up (knockoutjs)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've got a simple view-model going in KO:

```
        function TemplateFile(name, fileName) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = name;
            self.fileName = fileName;
        }

        var layoutViewModel = {
            loggedInUser: ko.observable("user"),
            templateFiles: ko.observableArray([
                // some initial entries...
            ]),
            contentHeading: ko.observable("Content"),
            // some other things...
        };

        $(function () { ko.applyBindings(layoutViewModel); });
```

And the data is bound in various points in my _Layout.cshtml partial view, most of them working fine. Except for this one...

```
        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="container-fluid" 
             style="background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; margin: 20px; min-height: 400px; height: auto !important; height: 400px">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h1 data-bind="text: contentHeading" style="color: darkgray;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

(ignore the inline CSS, that will be fixed soon ;))

The "contentHeading" data that's being bound to the h1 is not showing up at all. I tried several things already...

- Switching out the data that's being bound: still didn't show up
- Moving the tag around to different parts of the page: some worked, some randomly didn't
- Hard coding a dummy text value: this DID show up

So, given those results, I'm thinking there might be an issue with the how some of the DOM elements are being loaded, perhaps because I'm using Twitter Bootstrap?

I'm at a loss here, and can't seem to find a similar issue from anyone else. Any suggestions?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: templateFiles">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { title: fileName}" />
        <span data-bind="text: name" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can confirm the knockout works fine with bootstrap I am using it myself...but I am not too sure about why the code above is not working it looks okay to me.Does it give any error.Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I haven't really used jsFiddle before so I just threw in the code that I put here...let me know if that's not what I'm supposed to do! http://jsfiddle.net/mV6KQ/

Comment: I guess something wrong with context in code. Are you sure that you didn't place H1 withing with or foreach binding?

Comment: I actually do have a foreach further up, I thought it was closed properly...maybe not? Post edited to reflect what it is

Comment: D'oh! I see the issue now. It's not even related to knockout or bootstrap. I just didn't have my tags in order. -_-

Comment: In fact code you posted in fiddle works, you just forgot to reference jQuery. Here is fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/mV6KQ/1/. So something is wrong with a part of code you didn't post.

Comment: ha ha great that you found out the problem.Post your own answer and accept it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: templateFiles">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { title: fileName}" />
       <span data-bind="text: name" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

This isn't even related to knockout or bootstrap. I just have a tag mismatch. D'oh.

Closing this question! Thanks for the tips on what to look for :)